# Having problems with my screen

Tags: nvidia, screen, 19.10, intel

I'm having some problems on my screen on my recently installed Ubuntu 19.10, I feel that my screen lags or have some problems with refresh, it feels weird when I scroll down or up while web browsing or when I move program windows.
Some data: DellG7 Laptop, i7-8750H and GTX 1060 Max-Q, my integrated screen refresh rate is 60 hz. I'm attaching a video recorded with my phone to show the problem better.
[Ubuntu Screen Lagging problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u9vDFBI6z7E)
I'm kind of new in Linux, please be patient with me.

Comment: What version Nvidia drivers do you have installed?

Comment: I had 435, now I have 430 just for testing but still have the issue

Comment: According to https://www.geforce.com/drivers 440.82 is the current version.

Comment: I can only choose between 430, 435 and 390 in my Additional Drivers settings

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't download 440.82 and install it.